# Reactive forms Ionic 4, chamada de dados

Tags: html, angular, ionic, typescript, forms-authentication

eu usava o ngModel para pegar dados de uma api e passar para um formulario, onde o usuario digitava o cep e obtinha os dados, mas como vai ser descontinuado, vou mudar pra reactive forms, agora estou tendo um erro onde ao que parece os dados são zerados depois da busca

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { 
  Platform, 
  NavController,
  LoadingController
} from '@ionic/angular';

import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { BackendService } from 'src/app/services/backend.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-account-cnpj',
  templateUrl: './new-account-cnpj.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-account-cnpj.page.scss'],
})
export class NewAccountCnpjPage implements OnInit {
  dataCep: any = {logradouro: null, bairro: null, localidade: null}
  cnpj: any;
  dataCnpj: any;
  result: any;
  step: any = 1;
  delivery: any = -1;
  dataDelivery: any = {cep: null, logradouro: null};

  constructor(
   private platform: Platform,
   private authService: AuthService,
   private backendService: BackendService,
   private navCtrl: NavController,
    public loadingController: LoadingController,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) {}
    public user={
      numero: '198'
    }
    
    
      public errorMessages={
      log:[
        { type: 'required', message: 'Digite o Logradouro' },
        { type: 'minLength', message: 'Mínimo 2 letras'},
        { type: 'maxlength', message: 'Máximo 50 letras' }        
      ],        

      num:[
        { type: 'required', message: 'Digite o Número' },
        { type: 'pattern', message: 'Número inválido'},
        { type: 'minLength', message: 'Mínimo 1 número'},
        { type: 'maxlength', message: 'Máximo 15 números' }        
      ],
      
      bai:[
        { type: 'required', message: 'Digite o Bairro' },
        { type: 'minLength', message: 'Mínimo 2 letras'},
        { type: 'maxlength', message: 'Máximo 50 letras' }        
      ],
    
    
      cid:[
        { type: 'required', message: 'Digite a Cidade' },
        { type: 'minLength', message: 'Mínimo 2 letras'},
        { type: 'maxlength', message: 'Máximo 50 letras' }       
      ],
      state:[
        { type: 'required', message: 'Digite o Estado' },
        { type: 'minLength', message: 'Mínimo 2 letras'},
        { type: 'maxlength', message: 'Máximo 50 letras' }        
      ]
    };

    ValidateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      log: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50),Validators.minLength(2)]],
      num: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]'), Validators.maxLength(15),Validators.minLength(1)]],
      bai: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50),Validators.minLength(2)]],
      cid: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50),Validators.minLength(2)]],
      state: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50),Validators.minLength(2)]]
    });
    

  ngOnInit() {
  }



  async getCEP() {
   if(this.dataDelivery.cep.length == 9) {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
       message: 'Carregando',
       translucent: true,
       mode: 'ios'
     });
     loading.present().then( () => {
     this.backendService.getCEP(
         this.dataDelivery.cep,
         async result => {
           console.log('cep',JSON.stringify(result));
           this.ValidateForm.value = result;
           if(this.dataCep.erro == true) alert("CEP Inválido");
           //if(this.dataCep.logradouro) this.step = 4;
           await loading.dismiss();
         },
         async error => {
           await loading.dismiss();
           console.log(error);
         }
     );
     });
 } else this.dataCep = {};
  }
```

```html
<ion-item>
     <ion-label position="stacked" class="component-title">CEP</ion-label>
     <ion-input 
     type="text" placeholder="Insira o CEP aqui" [brmasker]="{mask:'00000-000', len:9}"[(ngModel)]="dataDelivery.cep" (keyup)="getCEP()" type="tel"  pattern="[0-9]*"></ion-input>
   </ion-item>
  
    <div *ngIf="ValidateForm.value?.logradouro">
    <form [formGroup]="ValidateForm">

     <ion-item>
     <ion-label position="stacked" class="component-title">Logradouro</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text" placeholder="rua, avenida, rodovia" formControlName="log" ></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
     
  

     <ion-item>
      <ion-label  style= "font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;" >Número</ion-label>   
     <ion-input type="text" placeholder="ex: 001" formControlName="num"></ion-input>
      <p style="font-size: 14px;">sem número</p><ion-toggle></ion-toggle>
     </ion-item>
     
  
     <ion-item>
     <ion-label position="stacked" class="component-title">Complemento</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text" placeholder="bloco, apartamento" ></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
     
  
     <ion-item>
     <ion-label position="stacked" class="component-title">Bairro</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text" placeholder="bairro" formControlName="bai" ></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
     

  
     <ion-item>
     <ion-label position="stacked" class="component-title">Cidade</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text" placeholder="cidade" formControlName="cid" ></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
   
  
     <ion-item>
     <ion-label position="stacked" class="component-title">UF</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text" placeholder="estado" formControlName= "state" ></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
     
   </form>
  
     <div style="text-align: center;">
    <ion-button [disabled]="!ValidateForm.valid" color="secondary" (click)="setStep(5)">
      Próximo
    </ion-button>
     </div>
    </div>
```

no html, eu uso um *ngIf para mostrar os dados do cep, após sua consulta, mas quando eu executo, ele roda por 1 segundo e os resultados somem, com o seguinte erro:

NewAccountCnpjPage.html:133 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: Avenida Dom Paulo Rolim Loureiro'. Current value: 'ngIf: undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

ValidateForm não tem logradouro,
deixe somente !ValidateForm.valid no if